# Is there a way to add animation for just one part of body?

Tags: unity, animation

I have 3D character. I added "walk" animation to it and as you know this animation effects all part of body. But I don't want animation effect upper body. Because I want character hands to stay the way I want(I made character upperbody look silly when it walks.).

I tried to change character upper body in animation tab manually but I couldn't. Its really hard to change all joints manually.

So, Is there a way to add animation for just one part of body ?

Comment: [What does the documentation have to say](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) about [masking animations to specific body parts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AvatarMask.html)?

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Really thanks @DMGregory

Comment: If you've solved your problem, want to write up the steps of your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is adding an avatar mask. When you create an avatar mask, you can choose which part of body you want to animate.

To create an avatar mask :

**Create -> Avatar Mask**

You can enable/disable body parts that you want to animate by this mask.
Then you should add this avatar mask to your animation layer. To do this :

There are layers tab in animator window. You should click gear icon in layer tab. And then pick which mask you want to apply.

[This video explains it well.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SAnr8-Xfgg)